# Futuristic GUI in Java?

Tags: java, user-interface

First of all sorry for my english, it's not my mother tongue.

I want to made a program in java, i was thinking that it will look great with a futuristic graphical user interface. When i say "futuristic", i mean something like this:

[image]

I know it's the image of an Android application but i'd like to do something like this in a java program.

Usually when i have to do GUIs in java i use `Swing` components, but now i need to personalize everything, and i'd also like that when i click "Send" for example the circle becomes bigger and other things appears inside it.

So i need to have a complitely personalized and animated GUI. Which is the best way to do it? Swing, Awt, JavaFx or what else?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: JavaFX I would use as of Java 8. It has nice animation effects, and CSS helps too. Also the usage of bound properties makes GUI programming a bit simpler. _I won't claim, it is easy though._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider to use JavaFX. It supports styling via CSS, has APIs for effects, animations etc. and can work with the graphic card.

Swing is currently in maintenance mode and JavaFX is the new proposed (by Oracle) standard Java GUI toolkit for Java.

Answer (score 1):

You could extend JComponent for every different component you want and then override the `paint(Graphics g)` method. Then you just draw on g object like on any other graphics object.